# PHP: Function to divide the time between two timestamps into equal intervals getting stuck

Tags: php, date, timestamp, associative-array, strtotime

I have a function where I pass total 5 parameters to it.

```
$Date1, $Time1, $Date2 and $Time2 and $Interval.
```

I first form a timestamp1 using Date1Time1, then form a timestamp2 using Date2Time2 , and then I divide these two timestamps into equal intervals of hours and then store into an associative array.

e.g.

```
$Date1 = 27-03-2016
$Time1 = 18:00
$Date2 = 27-03-2016
$Time2 = 21:00
```

Now I want to divide this time into equal time intervals of 60 mins, and then want to store into an associative array into below format.

$array = [27-03-2016 => 18:00 , 27-03-2016 => 19:00, 27-03-2016 => 20:00, 27-03-2016 => 21:00]

I have written below function in php. When I run this, the file is getting hanged forever and not responding anything and when I check the server logs then it gives 
error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded at line

```
$end_time = date('H-i',strtotime($end_timestamp));
```

As I am comparatively new to php, I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

```
function FindTimeSpan (&$Date1,&$Time1,&$Date2,&$Time2,&$Interval)
{
    $timespan=array($Date1 => $Time1);
    $timestamp1 = strtotime($Date1 . $Time1);
    $timestamp2 = strtotime($Date2 . $Time2);

    while( $Date1 < $Date2)
    {

        $start_timestamp = $timestamp1;
        $end_timestamp = $timestamp2 . '+' .$Interval;

        //Separating Date and Time from a timestamp
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end_timestamp));
        $end_time = date('H-i',strtotime($end_timestamp));

        //pushing value to an array
        $timespan = array_merge($timespan, array($end_date => $end_time));

        //setting the start value to the new end value
        $timestamp1 = $end_timestamp;
    }
    echo 'timestamp array' . json_encode($timespan);
}
```

Comment: You are never changing the values of `Date1` and `Date2`, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Your desired associative array format is impossible. You cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encounter is an infinite loop, which is caused by the condition `$Date1 < $Date2` . You don't modify any of these two values, so the condition will always be true. Strangely, you don't use the different `timestamp` values that are modified, but you should.

Concerning that, you should replace `$end_timestamp = $timestamp2 . '+' .$Interval;` by simply `$end_timestamp = $timestamp2 + $Interval ;` . Using the single quotes and the point will make PHP think of this as a string operation instead of a mathematical operation. With this and using this loop condition `$timestamp1 < $timestamp2`, your code should stop.

As said in a comment, your array structure is impossible because you can't assign have the same key multiple times. Instead of this, you should create an array per date and pushing the different times to these arrays.

To do this, you should first fix the way you retrieve the date and time in the loop. In the following code, the call to `strtotime` is unnecessary as the function `date` requires a timestamp, so no need to convert this back to a string.

```
    //Separating Date and Time from a timestamp
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end_timestamp));
    $end_time = date('H-i',strtotime($end_timestamp));
```

You should also be consistent, the format used here for the date is not consistent with the format you gave as exemple.

Answer (score 0):

Now as per your suggestions above, I have made few changes in my code as well as the requirement.

1. I have not decided to use Assoc array.
2. Instead I will divide the two stamps between equal timeintervals (assuming it is possible).
3. Then I am doing the simple array push of this string.
4. Later on once this array is form, I will parse it and take the Date and Time separate.

Now my code is not entering into infinite loop as I am comparing the two timestamps. But now, the issue is it is pushing the first value to the array but all the subsequent values are getting pushed as null

so the output I am getting from the below code is like
array[1459051200,null,null,null,......]

Below is the code

```
$Date1 = "2016-03-27";
$Time1 = "00:00";
$Date2 = "2016-03-30";
$Time2 = "22:00";
$Interval = '60';
FindTimeSpan ($Date1, $Time1, $Date2, $Time2, $Interval);
function FindTimeSpan (&$Date1,&$Time1,&$Date2,&$Time2,&$Interval)
{

$timestamp1 = strtotime($Date1 . $Time1);
$timespan=array();
array_push($timespan,$timestamp1);
echo 'Value of array timespan' . json_encode($timespan);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($Date2 . $Time2);

while( $timestamp1 < $timestamp2)
{

$start_timestamp = $timestamp1;
$end_timestamp = $timestamp1 + $Interval;

//pushing value to an array
array_push($timespan,$end_timespan);

//
$timestamp1 = $end_timestamp;

}
echo 'timestamp array' . json_encode($timespan);
}
```

Comment: I tried to debug my code....2 observations


1. The interval is in seconds to make it 1 hour, I make it 3600.

2. I am echoing the $end_timestamp, and it is calculating it correctly, but something wrong is happening when I am doing the array_push of this value and so it is getting pushed as null

Comment: Ahh...guys I got it....my bad.......I was pushing **$end_timespan** instead of **$end_timestamp** which is the correct name of the variable.....Silly me.....But thanks for the hints provided....This thread can be considered close.